# Checkbox for boolean value association in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a `User` model that has many `Subscription`s (categories of e-mail notifications). Whether a user receives e-mails corresponding to a given subscription depends on whether the `active` field in the subscription is true or false. I'm trying to use Simple Form's `association` method to allow users to subscribe or unsubscribe by changing the value of the `active` field:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email, label: "E-mail"
  = f.association :subscriptions, collection: @user.subscriptions,
    as: :check_boxes, value_method: :active, checked: lambda { |subscription| subscription.active? }

  = f.button :submit, "Save"
```

This does seem to correctly display the subscriptions with corresponding check boxes whose checked state corresponds to the value in the database. But checking or unchecking the boxes and submitting the form seems not to have any effect on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `simple_fields_for` here. That way it will be submitted as a nested form and be automatically saved in database. I'm not sure whether `association` can be used to save attributes of the associated model.

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email, label: "E-mail"
  - f.simple_fields_for :publications do |subscription|
    # Here you have all simple_form methods available
    = subscription.check_box :active

  = f.button :submit, "Save"
```

Also note that you will have to add accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions in the User model. And you will need to add this in your User model:

```
attr_accessible :subscriptions_attributes
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that `attr_accessible` isn't available in Rails 4. You'll need to add the relevant parameters to the whitelist in the User model. I had to include the Subscription `id` among these attributes; otherwise it would double the number of subscriptions each time the form was submitted.